# What package used in this image?

Tags: fncychap

I am trying to find the package used in this image to style the chapters of report. I tried all the options in `fncychap` with no luck. Can you tell what package is this ? [image]

Comment: The author might have customized a template for his own needs... In this case there is little chance to find it on the web.

Comment: If you need to identify the font, check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: For the font, I it looks a little similar to `cmbright`, but it's only similar. What do you think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something to get you started using `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\titlerule[2pt]
\vspace{4ex}\bfseries\sffamily\large}
{\filleft\Huge\thechapter}
{2ex}
{\filleft}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which means I have to customize everything, including. Chapters, Chapters with no numbers, contents.. Thanks you !